# jQuery slide up and slide down

Tags: jquery

By default only Questions to be displayed. On clicking any one of the questions related answer has to be displayed and other answers should be hidden. (Using slideUp and slideDown methods ).

Comment: you can use jquery Accordian......

Comment: Check this out: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 0):

You should use jquery toggle function

```
 <button>Toggle</button>
    <div class="que">
      <h4>Your Question One</h4>
       <p>
         Your Answer One!!
       </p>
     </div>
     <div class="que" style="display: none">
        <h4>Your Question Two</h4>
        <p>
          Your Answer Two!!
        </p>
   </div> 

   <script>
       $( "button" ).click(function() {
          $( ".que" ).toggle( "slow" );   

       });
   </script>
```

Check it here http://jsfiddle.net/k13oocfd/